# Safari: drop-shadow filter remains visible even with hidden element

Tags: html, css, safari

I'm applying drop-shadow filter to a div (dropdown) that is displayed and hidden as per user interaction, however, in Safari the drop-shadow  remains visible even when the element is hidden.

The bug happens only in Safari.

```js
document.querySelector('.bt').addEventListener('click', function () {
    let b = document.querySelector('.b');

    if (b.style.display === "none") {
        b.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        b.style.display = "none";
    }
})
```

```css
.bt {
    padding: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.a {
    height: 100px;
    padding: 20px;
    background: #ccc;
}

.b {
    position: relative;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: #0f0;
    filter: drop-shadow(0 0 0.125rem #000);
}

.b::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-right: .5rem solid transparent;
    border-left: .5rem solid transparent;
    border-bottom: .5rem solid #0f0;
    top: -.5rem;
    left: .5rem;
}
```

```html
<h1>drop-shadow filter bug with Safari</h1>

<button class="bt">CLICK ME!</button>

<div class="a">
    <div class="b">
        .b
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Safari is so bad. Try the fix in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35912155/1498053 (sorry not on a Mac right now, so I can't test it)

Comment: i just tested it on mac/safari and can confirm this bug. When you switch applications and go back to safari the filter gets removed but not reapplied again.

Comment: Workaround? `box-shadow: 0 0 0.125rem #000`. I have no Apple/Safari, but it might do the trick.

Comment: Thank you all for the quick response.

@elveti, I do not understand how -webkit-mask-image can solve my problem

Comment: @steven-kuipers, unfortunately the bug exists :(

Comment: @rene-van-der-lende, yes, box-shadow really solves this problem, but my case is a bit more complex, I will update the code snippet.

Answer (score 30):

I think I found a possible workaround.

Try adding `will-change: filter;` to your `.b { ... }` styles. The issue seems to be fixed this way.

Here is the code snippet with the fix:

```js
document.querySelector('.bt').addEventListener('click', function () {
    let b = document.querySelector('.b');

    if (b.style.display === "none") {
        b.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        b.style.display = "none";
    }
})
```

```css
.bt {
    padding: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.a {
    height: 100px;
    padding: 20px;
    background: #ccc;
}

.b {
    will-change: filter;
    position: relative;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: #0f0;
    filter: drop-shadow(0 0 0.125rem #000);
}

.b::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-right: .5rem solid transparent;
    border-left: .5rem solid transparent;
    border-bottom: .5rem solid #0f0;
    top: -.5rem;
    left: .5rem;
}
```

```html
<h1>drop-shadow filter bug with Safari</h1>

<button class="bt">CLICK ME!</button>

<div class="a">
    <div class="b">
        .b
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I had an issue where I was using a CSS filter drop-shadow on an element that was moving around the page - it was leaving a smear wherever it went on the page on iOS and Desktop Safari. This `will-change: filter;` fixed it! Thank you

Comment: This worked for me as well! I was using the `drop-shadow` filter on an absolute positioned drop-down menu. The shadow stuck around even after the menu disappeared. `will-change: filter;` was the fix I needed.

Comment: Had a similar issue with opacity transition on hover. `will-change: opacity;` also works for me, I stick to that because it's the attribute that actually changes.